# I'm trying to make a prediction model using keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network

When I try to make a convolutional neural network in keras and when I want to  check my model I got this error :

> **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'

the keras version that I am using is version  2.2.4

this is the model :

```py
input_shape = (224, 224, 1)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer='adam')


model.summary()
```

and the error is:

> **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem come from your last line :

```
model.add(Dense(activation='linear'))
```

You need to specify a size for your Dense layer so either you do this :

```
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(NEWSIZE, activation='linear')) #
```

With NEWSIZE being the number of units you want

or this :

```
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
```